# Firebase web version 9 getDocs() hangs while paginating

Tags: reactjs, firebase, google-cloud-firestore

I am paginating a firebase collection and displaying the data in a Material UI table. The logic works, but what I'm noticing is there will be random times, the getNextPage function or the getPreviousPage function will randomly hang at the line where getDocs(q) is happening.  I have console logs testing this and it never goes past the getDocs(q) when the method does hang.  I'm wondering why might this be.  Is it logic causing this? Is it my network causing this? is it firebase not working as it should? I'm console logging the firstVisibleDoc and lastVisibleDoc and it is always the correct one for the query I'm using.  It's very hard to diagnose this as there is no real error handling that's possible with getDocs() in firebase web version 9.  Please let me know any and all feedback and suggestions you might have.  I am just trying to diagnose as to why when I hit the next page or previous page button on the table does it just hang and not fetch anything at random times.

```
const Table = () => {
  const navigate = useNavigate()
  const [selectedValue, setSelectedValue] = useState('')
  const [tabValue, setTabValue] = useState(0)
  const [rows, setRows] = useState([])
  const [loading, setLoading] = useState(true)
  const [rowsPerPage, setRowsPerPage] = useState(5)
  const [hasMore, setHasMore] = useState(true)
  const [lastVisibleDoc, setLastVisibleDoc] = useState(null)
  const [firstVisibleDoc, setFirstVisibleDoc] = useState(null)
  const [page, setPage] = useState(0)

  useEffect(() => {
    console.log('this is running')
    const fetchData = async () => {
      let q = query(
        collection(db, 'appointments.requests'),
        orderBy('created'),
        limit(rowsPerPage + 1)
      )

      const querySnapshot = await getDocs(q)

      const initialData = querySnapshot.docs.map((doc) => ({
        id: doc.id,
        ...doc.data()
      }))

      setFirstVisibleDoc(querySnapshot.docs[0])

      if (querySnapshot.docs.length <= rowsPerPage) {
        setHasMore(false)
        setLastVisibleDoc(querySnapshot.docs[querySnapshot.docs.length - 1])
      } else {
        setHasMore(true)
        setLastVisibleDoc(querySnapshot.docs[querySnapshot.docs.length - 2])
      }

      setRows(initialData.slice(0, rowsPerPage))
      setLoading(false)
    }

    fetchData()
  }, [rowsPerPage])

  const getNextPage = async () => {
    const q = query(
      collection(db, 'appointments.requests'),
      orderBy('created'),
      startAfter(lastVisibleDoc),
      limit(rowsPerPage + 1)
    )
  
    console.log(lastVisibleDoc)
    // it hangs here
    const querySnapshot = await getDocs(q)
    console.log('getNextSnapshot', querySnapshot)

    const allData = querySnapshot.docs.map((doc) => ({
      id: doc.id,
      ...doc.data()
    }))

    setFirstVisibleDoc(querySnapshot.docs[0])
    if (allData.length <= rowsPerPage) {
      setHasMore(false)
      setLastVisibleDoc(querySnapshot.docs[querySnapshot.docs.length - 1])
    } else {
      setHasMore(true)
      setLastVisibleDoc(querySnapshot.docs[querySnapshot.docs.length - 2])
    }

    setRows([...allData.slice(0, rowsPerPage)])
    setPage((prevState) => prevState + 1)
  }

  const getPreviousPage = async () => {
    const q = query(
      collection(db, 'appointments.requests'),
      orderBy('created'),
      endAt(firstVisibleDoc),
      limitToLast(rowsPerPage + 1)
    )
  
    console.log(firstVisibleDoc)
    // it hangs here
    const querySnapshot = await getDocs(q)
    console.log('getPreviousSnapshot', querySnapshot)
    const allData = querySnapshot.docs.map((doc) => ({
      id: doc.id,
      ...doc.data()
    }))

    setFirstVisibleDoc(querySnapshot.docs[0])

    setLastVisibleDoc(querySnapshot.docs[querySnapshot.docs.length - 2])

    setRows([...allData.slice(0, rowsPerPage)])
    setPage((prevState) => prevState - 1)
    setHasMore(true)
  }

  const handlePageChange = (event, newValue, page) => {
    console.log(newValue, page)

    if (newValue > page) {
      getNextPage()
    } else {
      getPreviousPage()
    }
  }


  return (
    <Paper>
      <TableContainer
        component={Paper}
        elevation={0}
        sx={{
          overflowX: 'auto',
          minHeight: '200px'
        }}
      >
        <MuiTable elevation={0}>
          <TableHead sx={{ backgroundColor: '#f8f9fa' }}>
           ... the table head
          </TableHead>
          <TableBody sx={{ minHeight: '400px' }}>
           ... the table body
          </TableBody>
        </MuiTable>
      </TableContainer>
      <TablePagination
        component='div'
        count={-1}
        rowsPerPage={rowsPerPage}
        page={page}
        onPageChange={(e, newValue) => handlePageChange(e, newValue, page)}
        onRowsPerPageChange={(event) =>
          setRowsPerPage(parseInt(event.target.value, 10))
        }
        labelDisplayedRows={({ from, to }) => {
          return `${from}-${to}`
        }}
        rowsPerPageOptions={[5, 10, 25]}
        nextIconButtonProps={{ disabled: !hasMore }}
      />
    </Paper>
  )
}

export default Table
```

Comment: I recommend putting `try-catch` block inside the `useEffect` callback, and seeing if there's an error being raised.

Comment: The useEffect isn't the issue, it runs on mount and fetches the initial docs and I never run into an issue with that.  It's the getNextPage and getPreviousPage.  I've tried wrapping the getDocs(q) a try catch and no error ever displays.  It just seems like the getDocs promise never resolves